# How to return a clicked element

Tags: jquery, css

I would like have the `id="nm"` when I click on `<ul>` inside the `div`.
this is the html.

```
<div id="suggestionTags">
   <ul>
      <li class="nm">Commonwealth</li>
      <span class="cty"> x GB</span>
      <li class="hse">Commonwealth</li>
      <li class="yrs">1649-1653</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="nm">Oliver Cromwell</li>
      <span class="cty"> x GB</span>
      <li class="hse">Commonwealth</li>
      <li class="yrs">1653-1658</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="nm">Richard Cromwell</li>
      <span class="cty"> x GB</span>
      <li class="hse">Commonwealth</li>
      <li class="yrs">1658-1659</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="nm">Elizabeth II ((Head of the Commonwealth of Nations))</li>
      <span class="cty"> x GB</span>
      <li class="hse">House of Windsor</li>
      <li class="yrs">1952-</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the part of javascript:

```
$("#suggestionTags").on('click',function(){
    alert( $(this).find("li.nm").text() );
});
```

This code gives me everithing and not only the id="nm" of the clicked 
Someone can help me?

**EDIT**:

Into http://jsfiddle.net/ the proposed solutions  work weel. However I still get a problem.
I'll post my code, that maybe can be the problem.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

     $(document).ready(function()

            {
//this is the code that does'nt work
            $('#suggestionTags ul').on('click', function() {
                alert($(this).find("li.nm").text());
            });
//end of part
                var o = [];
                $('#scrivo').keyup(function()
                {
                    if ($('#scrivo').val() <= 0) {
                        $('#suggestionTags').empty();
                        return;
                    }
                    var json = (function() {
                        var json = null;
                        $.ajax({
                            'async': false,
                            'global': false,
                            'url': "re.json",
                            'dataType': "json",
                            'success': function(data) {
                                json = data;
                            }
                        });
                        return json.Re;
                    })();
                    o = $.grep(json, function(n) {
                        return n.nm.indexOf($('#scrivo').val()) !== -1;
                    }, false);
                    $('#suggestionTags').empty();
                    var html = "";
                    $.each(o, function(index, value) {
                        html += '<ul>';
                        $.each(value, function(i, v) {
                            switch (i) {
                                case "nm":
                                    html += "<li class='nm'>" + v + "</li>";
                                    break;
                                case "cty":
                                    html += "<span class='cty'> x " + v + "</span>";
                                    break;
                                case "hse":
                                    html += "<li class='hse'>" + v + "</li>";
                                    break;
                                case "yrs":
                                    html += "<li class='yrs'>" + v + "</li>";
                                    break;
                            }
                            ;
                        });
                        html += "</ul>";


                    });
                    $('#suggestionTags').append(html);
                });

            });

        </script>
```

I explain my code: the code retrieve a json file and than the `<input>` filter the `var o` with the keyup finction. The filtered array of objects are displayed in the `#suggestionTags <div>`.
The json is like this:

```
{
  "Re": 
[
  {
    "nm": "Edward the Elder",
    "cty": "GB",
    "hse": "House of Wessex",
    "yrs": "899-925"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Edgar",
    "cty": "GB",
    "hse": "House of Wessex",
    "yrs": "959-975"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Edward the Martyr",
    "cty": "GB",
    "hse": "House of Wessex",
    "yrs": "975-978"
  }
 ]
}
```

I d'ont understand why this code doesn't work as espected. But if I change this line of code

```
$('#suggestionTags ul').on('click', function() {
                alert($(this).find("li.nm").text());
            });
```

with
this

```
$('#suggestionTags').on('click', function() {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
```

In the alert popup I can see everyting filtered object. But I can't retrive the part of html that I clicked.

Comment: $("#suggestionTags ul").on...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
$("#suggestionTags li").on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('ul').find("li.nm").text());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D9g2b/)**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your jQuery selector:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfc4K/)

```
$("#suggestionTags ul").on('click',function(){
    alert( $(this).find("li.nm").text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for my question the solution is:

```
    $('#suggestionTags').on('click','ul', function() {
        alert($(this).find('li.nm').text());
    });
```

I didn't understand why the others solutions don't work with my whole code, but used alone they work great!?!